# Using to mock a method call

Tags: java, mockito

I am testing a class and want to mock a method call in it:

```
class B{

  method A();

  String method C();

}
```

Now, I want to test method `A`, and mock call to method `C`, as method `C` reads input from a URL. How can I do this using Mockito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of options here.

Probably the simplest - you could use a mockito spy (http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13), which is an object where you can stub some of the methods, and the others retain their existing behaviour.

Or, you could use a mock, and then stub methodA using either the static doCallRealMethod method, using when in combination with thenCallRealMethod.

But best of all in my opinion would be to refactor your class so that the part that reads from the URL is in a separate class.  Then write a unit test for class B, using a mock for the separate class.  Then write an integration test for the class that reads from the URL.

Please post a comment here if this approach is not clear; I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: well, its seem not good practice to create a totally different classs just to do I/O at one point? dont u think so ?

Comment: I don't agree with you.  But that's why I suggested three different solutions; if you don't like one, then pick one of the others.

Answer (score 0):

actually when mocking an object (a least with mockito) you mock the whole object and without using some unrecommended call which all contain this in their doc :

> As usual you are going to read the partial mock warning: Object oriented programming is more less tackling complexity by dividing the complexity into separate, specific, SRPy objects. How does partial mock fit into this paradigm? Well, it just doesn't... Partial mock usually means that the complexity has been moved to a different method on the same object. In most cases, this is not the way you want to design your application.

So two solution possible:

1 - you redesign your class so that methodC is in an aggregated class of your actual classB, after that you can inject the new class that can be totally mocked in the tested classB. As a bonus you get a better separation of task as all outside world interaction should be separately encapsulated to help testing and maintaining it when the outside source change (but I don't know specifically what your method A and C does)

2-in you test class you could extend ClassB and override the methodC, that result in a sort of manual mocking and doesn't require any mocking framework, but the mockito partial warning can still hold here.

Hope this help